# What's wrong with this indexOf implementation?

Tags: javascript

I know I'm leaving out the -1 option when value can't be found, but why doesn't it work when the value is in the Array? It should be returning 1, but is returning undefined.

```
function each(collection, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      callback(collection[i], i, collection);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (var prop in collection) {
      callback(collection[prop], prop, collection);
    }
  }
}

function indexOf(array, value) {
  each(array, function(e, index) {
    if (e === value) {
      return index; 
    }
  })
}


console.log(indexOf([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)); ---->>> undefined;
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is supported by latest browsers

Comment: practice with javascript fundamentals

Comment: To be fair, if fixed, this wouldn't do the same thing as the native indexOf: this version would also allow you to discover the first property ("index") having a specified value on an object. Of course, then you might run into issues with non-guaranteed property iteration order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the value of index within the callback, not within the `indexOf()` function itself.

Try this implementation:

```
function indexOf(array, value) {
   var returnVal = -1;
   each(array, function(e, index) {
        if (e === value) {
            returnVal = index; 
            return false;
        }
    });
    return returnVal;
}
```

EDIT: As Barmar pointed out, this will return the index of the last occurrence of the element, to return the index of the first occurrence, you'll also have to update `each()` to be:

```
function each(collection, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            if (callback(collection[i], i, collection) === false) break;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var prop in collection) {
            if (callback(collection[prop], prop, collection) === false) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will return the value of the LAST occurrence of the element, not the first, because `each()` doesn't stop calling the callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
function indexOf(array, value) {
  each(array, function(e, index) {
    if (e === value) {
      return index; 
    }
  })
}
```

The return here is returning from the function that is being passed to `each` and not from your `indexOf` function.  You need to somehow get that value outside of that function scope to return.  With your current implementation of each, you would not be able to break the loop, so you would have to do something like this:

```
function indexOf(array, value) {
  var result = -1;

  each(array, function(e, index) {
    if (e === value) {
      result = index; 
    }
  })

  return result;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efzogzxq/

Answer (score 1):

Your `indexOf()` function isn't returning anything. The callback returns the index if found, but you're not doing anything with that value. You could do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  var result= callback(collection[i], i, collection);
  if (result) return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to return the index if found. Also, you need to *exit the loop once you've found the value*, otherwise you're doing a `lastIndexOf` instead of `indexOf`.

```
function each(collection, callback) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            if (callback(collection[i], i, collection) === true) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var prop in collection) {
            if (callback(collection[prop], prop, collection) === true) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

function indexOf(array, value) {
    var foundIndex = -1;

    each(array, function(e, index) {
        if (e === value) {
            foundIndex = index;
            return true;
        }
    });

    return foundIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf function is always returning undefined because the you are only returning a value from the callback function, not the indexOf function.

Try this:

```
function indexOf(array, value) {
    var i;

    each(array, function(e, index) {
        if (e === value) {
            i = index; 
        }
    })

   return i;
}
```